# JavaScript - convert data base64 string to image

Tags: javascript, cordova, base64

I am making a mobile app using PhoneGap and I want to convert data base64 string to a file and save it in the mobile device.

How can I convert data base64 string to image file using JavaScript? Is there any JavaScript library that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use Data URLs:

```
<a href="data:jpg/image;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR...." target="_blank">
```

this also works in img-Tags:

```
<img src="data:jpg/image;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR...." />
```

To trigger this by pure JavaScript, maybe this could work. The back-end should behave like a DOM browser:

```
var content = "data:jpg/image;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR....";
var window = window.open(content, "Image");
window.focus()
```

Comment: I want to **convert data base64 string to a file and save it** in the mobile device.

Comment: you need to trick the device to trigger a file download, maybe my Edit helps?